# Do something if cell is selected/active?

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple data sets to be plotted using VBA. Each data set (X and Y values) as as whole is tagged by a cell (say Data1 and so on). What I want to do is to plot the data set whose tag is selected by user.

There may be multiple tags selected by the user at the same time. Also user might have imported many data sets in active sheet, but only the data sets whose tag (cell) is activated should be plotted.
Is this possible? How can I do it?

Comment: Try to record a macro of you selecting a cell, hence the below range and plotting it into the chart. Hence, use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event to detect when the user is selecting the right cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Worksheet_SelectionChange procedure for the worksheet where the tags are located to figure out when a user makes a new selection.

Furthermore, if you create a named range containing the tags you could use the following code to figure out when one of the tags is selected:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
dim rCell as Range

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, _TagNamedRange_ )
    For each rCell in Target
        'code to determine which specific tag was selected
    Next
End If

End Sub
```